# Join two tables without merging in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to join the tables without merging them and creating one table. for e.g. I have two tables as given in the below screenshot. I have closely placed tables with 1pt font size between them. I want to have a structure where the table will look as if it is joined but every row will be a different table.

Is it possible to do it in Microsoft Word?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgpV6.jpg)

Comment: Selecting the paragraph mark between each table and marking it as hidden (Home->Font->Check the Hidden box) is probably the simplest way.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. space was still visible, there should be no space between two tables.

Comment: Did you change the view so that hidden text is not shown? That’s the problem with hidden text it’s visible until you hide it. The only other way I have done this kind of thing is to make each table “floating” (rather than “in line with text”  - select the table by its selection box and drag it somewhere. But organising more than around 2 or 3 separate rows into something that looks like a single table seems very difficult.

Comment: Can you say why you need these rows to be separate tables?

Comment: Actually we are using a third-party tool in salesforce which uses Microsoft word while creating and generating the documents. while generating the document we are facing an issue where the alignment of the table is getting changed if there is splitting and merging in the table. The tool does not support splitting and merging of the table. and so that tool's support team suggested us to create a separate table for each row and keep the 1pt distance between it. we have done that but it does not look good and also the page size is getting increased.

Comment: I wondered if there might be another way but those are the two main things other than perhaps "use a background image to provide the table lines and spend a lot of time arranging your text and fields (if that is what they are) to fit. BTW you should be able to go down to 0.7pt by changing the paragraph Line Spacing to Exactly 0.7pt.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the P paragraph marker (show first) and click 'cut' this removes the space between the two tables and 'rejoins' them.